# Security Threat/Attack to JSF Application after enabling HTTPS

Tags: security, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2

I have a JSF2.0 based web application on RF3.3 running on JBoss.
I am very concerned with the security of the web application.

Although the communication to my Web App from the external world would be on HTTPS, I still don't know after enabling HTTPS for my web application what other security attacks are possible.

At the very least, there are a gamut of security attacks for web application but my focus is on OWASP top 10 security attacks.

JSF automatically handles XSS and CSRF attacks (I have also used ESAPI jar to avoid CSRF attack) and I have already taken care of SQL injection attack.

I feel even after enabling https there would be too many well known and potential threats/attacks to web application.

Another thing I would like to inform:-
The customer would be accessing the application on HTTPS. But my application will raise certain kind of request to another internal web application and this communication is HTTP. So there will be a change of protocol from HTTPS to HTTP but since this change is on intranet I think it won't affect much.

Please guide me.

Comment: If the HTTP connection is purely server side over the local network, then this should be secure assuming the local network is trustworthy. Depending on what the data is though, you might want this locked down by using a dedicated connection rather than sharing the local network with other users (if that is the case).

Comment: If you built your app to be secure (that is, if you do proper in- and output sanitization where needed), then I don't see why this site shouldn't go live. If you've failed to do this, this is a different problem.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Perhaps you have almost answered my question.I am using a dedicated connection for switching between HTTP and HTTPS..Since the HTTP connection is purely to another web application hosted by me so I am sure about the security of the local network.

Answer (score 3):

> JSF automatically handles XSS

This is not true.
Yes, JSF does auto-escaping by default, so [`h:outputText`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html) and others will escape HTML special characters properly:

> **escape  Boolean**
>
> The escape attribute is a boolean flag that determines **if sensitive HTML and XML characters should be escaped** in the output generated by this component. The default value for this attribute is `"true"`.

This blocks injection of `<script>` tags, but does not affect other major XSS vectors. `javascript:` URLs need not contain any "sensitive HTML or XML characters", and HTML sensitive characters in `javascript:` URLs injected into `<img src=...>` and `<a href="...">`  will just be properly escaped easing the attack.

Any URLs that are composed from untrusted data should be checked for well-formedness and their protocol should be white-listed against a small set.  "http", "https", and "mailto" are good defaults for most applications.

---

> I feel even after enabling https there would be too many well known and potential threats/attacks to web application.

Site-wide HTTPs is a great step.  If you have locked down XSS, XSRF, and eavesdropping, the next attack vector I would try is [header-splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting).

If I can insert a `Location` header into your page, I can cause a redirect possibly carrying referrer info with GET parameters to a site I control.

Comment: I have handled XSRF, XSS and SQL injection attack from my end. I am not sure of header splitting hence I cannot comment on that.But should I conclude that whatever attacks/threats are mentioned above, only those need to be handled for making a web app safe over the internet.Although no web application is safe I just want to handle major attacks/threats on the web applications.

Comment: @Hukamanata, No.  "XSRF", "XSS", and "SQL Injection" are useful labels for patterns of vulnerability, but any security posture based on partitioning vectors into labelled buckets is [enumerating badness](http://www.ranum.com/security/computer_security/editorials/dumb/).  Real security requires upfront design: approximating [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) application wide, [separation of privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) (POLA per-module), and [defense-in-depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29).